# intellij idea: how to diff contents of a folder (recursively) against latest (or earlier) revision in SCM repo (e.g., Git ?)

Tags: git, version-control, intellij-idea

I'm working with a project imported from maven (but i don't think the build framework matters)..

anyway.. if i right click on one of the files in the project and select Git (my SCM system) i see an option 'compare with same repository version'.
However, if i right click on the containing folder of this file this option is grayed out.

i can request  Git / Show History.. but when i click on and entry (e.g., the latest revision), and then select  'compare with local'  i get an error dialog that say  'not applicable to the file:  file://home/me/project/etc/etc....'

I've done this in the past with IDEA.. now i can't get it to work..    did something break or change.. ?   or did i just forget how it is done?

thanks !
  chris

Answer (score 2):

I answered my question in my previous post. Now I'm realizing it is NOT the answer that I (or presumably anyone else in this situation) really want.
The above answer lets you get a tree view of files from the last check in and see any diffs between the current state of the file in your project and that checked in version. That is sort of what I want.
But this limits you to looking at diffs only on the files that you happened to check in last time.

What if last time you checked in file `a`, `b`, and `c`, and since the last check in you modified `a`, `b`, and `x`?
Well you are out of look as far as using this method to review the diffs on `x`.

But there is another way... it is sort of a hack, but it works.   what you do is:

1. make a recursive copy of the current contents of your project to /tmp/current
2. do a `git stash` to get your project in the state of the last check in (no changes)
   Don't worry you can recover in subsequent steps.
3. next go to the top level folder in the Project view of Intellij (the same one you copied to `/tmp/current`, then right click and select '`Compare Directory With`'  select `/tmp/current` as the target to compare against.
4. Now you will see all your diffs from the latest check in in a nicely organized list.
5. after you finish your review, do a  '`git stash pop`'  to get the changes back to the folder where you have your project.

I don't know why there is not an easier way to do this.
I'm going to file a bug with IntelliJ and ask for something more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this question my self  (for anyone who is interested).

The way to do this is to **select the revision you wish to examine diffs for, then click on show all affected paths**.
This will give you a tree view of the files in that check in.

Using this tree view  you can select '`Show Diff`' on any artifact, and you can see the difference between the state of the artifact as of that revision diff'd with the state of the artifact immediately prior to that revision.

This is basically what I want..   The diffs are side by side which is very helpful.

Now, I have not figured out how you can get a diff between two arbitrary revisions (SHA's) in the repo... this technique just seems to work for a diffing a given revision and the revision immediately before it.

I see other questions on Stack Overflow on how to get side-by-side diffs of GIT repo revisions. Well this seems to do the trick  (in most cases).
This is yet another reason why Intellij is pretty cool  (I don't work for them, I just like the product).